# How in a step definition to apply selection of locators

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I have a question in regards to using multiple locators using the By statement.

Below I have in my a piece of code where it will type into a field based on the by clause:

```
    public void GetFieldAndEnterText(By fieldElement, string fieldText) =>
        _driver.FindElement(fieldElement).SendKeys(fieldText);
```

In my step definition I am struggling to work out how to determine which locator to use based on the filed mentioned in the specflow step.

I have these steps:

```
When I enter in invalid email Test.TestEmail.plc for Email address field
    And I enter in invalid email Test.TestEmail.gmail.com for Confirm email address field
```

I virtually want it to be if the field is Email address then use this locator:

```
_payment.GetFieldAndEnterText(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.EmailAddressField);
```

if the field is confirm email address:

```
_payment.GetFieldAndEnterText(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.ConfirmEmailAddressField);
```

How can I apply this in my step definition below?

```
 [When(@"I enter in invalid email (.*) for (.*) field")]
    public void WhenIEnterInInvalidEmailForField(string fieldText, By fieldElement)
    {
            _payment.GetFieldAndEnterText(fieldElement, fieldText);
    }
```

Comment: Why go into that kind of detail? You can create one or two steps. When I enter in invalid email into the address field    And I enter in an invalid Confirm email address or when I enter address test@no.com and confirm email address test1@no.com Then I shoul dget a mismatch error. Then you do two entries based on the string field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do something like this. I used a scenario outline but you could do it without.

```
Given on the <Field> I enter <Value>
And I click the sign in button 
Then I can validate the <ErrorMessage> is thrown for <Field>

        Examples: 
         | Field    | Value | ErrorMessage|                                                      
         | email    | N/A | Email is required. |                                                 
         | password | N/A  | Password is required|  

    [Given(@"on the (.*) I enter (.*)")]
    public void GivenOnTheEmailIEnterNA(string field, string value)
    {
        switch (field.ToLower())
        {
            case "email":
                CallYourElement.TypeEmail(value.ToLower() == "n/a" ? "" : value);
                break;
            case "password":
                CallYourElement.TypePassword(value.ToLower() == "n/a" ? "" : value);
                break;
        }
    }


   [Then(@"I can validate the (.*) is thrown for (.*)")]
    public void ThenICanValidateTheEmailIsRequired_IsThrownForEmail(string expectedError, string field)
    {
        switch (field.ToLower())
        {
            case "email":
            {
                var receivedError = CallYourElement.GetEmailRequiredError();

                 Assert.AreEqual(expectedError, receivedError);
             }
                break;

            case "password":
            {
                var receivedError2 = CallYourElement.GetEmailPasswordRequiredError();

                    Assert.AreEqual(expectedError, receivedError2);

            }
                break;
        }
    }
```